# How to get all similar named records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing data stored like:

```
product_name | quantity | tert
ASIZ A4 100 FOX | 20| BUYER1
CERVEZA A6 150 FOX | 15| BUYER1
ASIZ A4 150 FOX | 40| BUYER1   
CERVEZA A6 11 FOX | 15| BUYER1
QUINTA A6 150 FOX | 15| BUYER2
ASIZ A4 150 FOX | 33 | BUYER2
ASIZ A6 150 FOX | 15| BUYER2
CERVEZA A6 150 FOX | 15| BUYER2
```

I want to retrieve all data that matches first word (e.g. **ASIZ**) sum the quantities and display them like:

```
BUYER1
Asiz - 60 pcs.
Cerveza = 30 pcs.
etc.

BUYER2
Asiz = 48 pcs.
Cerveza = 15 pcs.
```

etc

at the moment I am using 2 while loops:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_name 
FROM my_table 
WHERE buyer_code= '".$bcode."' 
GROUP BY product_name
```

-- and I get the product names

then

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_name,tert, SUM(quantity) AS quantity 
FROM my_table 
WHERE buyer_code ='".$bcode."' AND 
      prouct_name LIKE '".$first_word_of_product_name."%' 
GROUP BY tert
ORDER BY data ASC
```

I get the sums right, but it lists them every time it finds similar named products (eg: **BUYER1: ASIZ - 2 times** etc.)

it shows:

```
Buyer1
ASIZ - 60
Cerveza - 30
ASIZ - 60
Cerveza - 30
```

I know it has something to do with the product_name, but how should I write the sql statement to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
SELECT tert, SUBSTRING_INDEX(product_name,' ',1) as product, sum(quantity) as qty
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY tert, product
ORDER BY tert, product
```

Your results are sorted by *tert* so ou can walk through one by one showing *product* and *qty* and displaying *tert* every time a *tert* changes.

**UPDATE**:
A code sample how to output the data (not tested):

```
$tert = null;
foreach($rows as $row){
    if($rows['tert'] != $tert){
        $tert = $rows['tert'];
        echo $tert;
    }
    echo $row['product'], "-", $row['qty'];
}
```

here `$rows` - all fetched rows.

Comment: i need to print ASIZ - 60 pieces (generic product, includes 30 ASIZ simple, 20 Asiz superior and 10 Asiz simplex) 
NOT
Asiz simple -30 
etc -- list of data

Comment: @user1638656 That's exactly what `SUBSTRING_INDEX(product_name,' ',1) as product` and `GROUP BY tert,product` do.

Comment: @user1638656 I fixed `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: OR should I ask: how to display the data returned, grouped by first word of the name of product and the sum of quantities..?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(product_name, '.', 1) product, tert, SUM(quantity) quantity
FROM my_table
GROUP BY product, tert
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tert` from your second sql and it would work as expected.

Change this to

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_name,tert, SUM(quantity) AS quantity 
FROM my_table 
WHERE buyer_code ='".$bcode."' 
     AND prouct_name LIKE '".$first_word_of_product_name."%' 
GROUP BY tert 
ORDER BY data ASC
```

this

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_name, SUM(quantity) AS quantity 
FROM my_table 
WHERE buyer_code ='".$bcode."' 
     AND prouct_name LIKE '".$first_word_of_product_name."%' 
GROUP BY product_name 
ORDER BY data ASC
```

Comment: nope, it just lists all records, each time it finds a product (eg: for buyer1 - lists asiz -60 twice

Comment: Opp. Edited. `Group by` was using `tert`. If you want the sum of quatities grouping over product_name then this sql should work. Please check.